# Trying to make a radio button group with BEMCheckBoxes

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I'd like to make a radio button group that will be like this when nothing is checked already using [BEMCheckBoxes](https://github.com/Boris-Em/BEMCheckBox):

[image]

It appears to me that I can't simply add the number in the button.

So I decided to make a view with a label and a checkbox centered in it.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
// Add An horizontal stackView with check group
UIStackView uIStackView = new UIStackView();
uIStackView.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
uIStackView.Axis = UILayoutConstraintAxis.Horizontal;
uIStackView.Alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.Center;
qolEvaluationCard.AddSubview(uIStackView);
uIStackView.Anchor(top: criteria.BottomAnchor, leading: criteria.LeadingAnchor, trailing: criteria.TrailingAnchor, size: new CGSize(0, 32));
BEMCheckBoxGroup bEMCheckBoxGroup = new BEMCheckBoxGroup();
bEMCheckBoxGroups.Add(bEMCheckBoxGroup);
for (int score= 1; score <= 10; score++)
{
   var container = new UIView(new CGRect(0, 0, 32, 32));
   var label = new UILabel();
   label.Text = $@"{score}";
   label.TintColor = UIColor.Black;
   container.AddSubview(label);
   var checkbox = new BEMCheckBox(new CGRect(0, 0, 32, 32));
   container.AddSubview(checkbox);
   checkbox.BoxType = BEMBoxType.Circle;
   checkbox.OnAnimationType = BEMAnimationType.Stroke;
   checkbox.Center = label.Center = new CGPoint(container.Frame.Size.Width / 2, container.Frame.Size.Height / 2);
   // Transparent BackgroundColor
   checkbox.BackgroundColor = null;
   checkbox.TintColor = UIColor.Gray;
   checkbox.OnTintColor = optimistic_orange;
   bEMCheckBoxGroup.AddCheckBoxToGroup(checkbox);
   uIStackView.AddArrangedSubview(container);
}
```

The result is not what I expect but I can't figure out what is wrong:

[image]

Why are my checkboxes not transparent to let appear the label?
There is also a problem of distribution within the UIStackView obviously.

Any help appreciated.

The Anchor extension method is:

```
internal static void Anchor(this UIView uIView, NSLayoutYAxisAnchor top = null, NSLayoutXAxisAnchor leading = null, NSLayoutYAxisAnchor bottom = null, NSLayoutXAxisAnchor trailing = null, UIEdgeInsets padding = default, CGSize size = default)
{
    uIView.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    if (top != null)
    {
        uIView.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(top, padding.Top).Active = true;
    }

    if (leading != null)
    {
        uIView.LeadingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(leading, padding.Left).Active = true;
    }

    if (bottom != null)
    {
        uIView.BottomAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(bottom, -padding.Bottom).Active = true;
    }

    if (trailing != null)
    {
        uIView.TrailingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(trailing, -padding.Right).Active = true;
    }

    if (size.Width != 0)
    {
        uIView.WidthAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(size.Width).Active = true;
    }

    if (size.Height != 0)
    {
        uIView.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(size.Height).Active = true;
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1**: Just found out with the help of the Reveal tool that My labels size was ambiguous.

> var label = new UILabel();

becomes

> var label = new UILabel(new CGRect(0, 0, 32, 32));

This solves the 'invisible label' issue.

Comment: Hi , how about using `UICollectionView` to implement that , you can custom item template to show your want . https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/controls/uicollectionview

Answer (score 0):

my answer is **Swift** codes, but give You concept of works.
I suggest You to break down problem to simple steps.
 just try to layout checkboxes (`BEMCheckBox`) correctly on `UIStackView`, then create custom View that contain `UILabel` + `BEMCheckBox` and now add them to `UIStackView` and review layout.

### Why label not appear on checkbox?

because you add label first, then you put checkbox on it.

```
container.addSubview(checkbox)
container.addSubview(label)
```

---

### Setup StackView:

to achive checkboxes horizontal layout

```
let stackView: UIStackView = {
    let stack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: customCheckboxes)
    stack.spacing = 8
    stack.distribution = .fillEqually
    stack.axis = .horizontal
    stack.alignment = .fill
    return stack
}()
```

then snap stackView to corners using autoLayout or whatever

*I think using `UIStackView` is the best choice, don't use `UICollectionView` for this simple condition.*

---

### How to update label state when checkbox selected?

I didn't use `BEMCheckBoxGroup` before, but just reviewed source codes and there is a function `notifyCheckBoxSelectionChanged` trigger when checkbox selection change.

```
func notifyCheckBoxSelectionChanged(_ checkBox: BEMCheckBox) {
        if checkBox.on {
            // Change selected checkbox to this one
            selectedCheckBox = checkBox
        } else if checkBox == selectedCheckBox {
            // Selected checkbox was this one, clear it
            selectedCheckBox = nil
        }
    }
```

but it's not pubic, `selectedCheckBox` is what you need to know about this group. I think you should add target on `valueChanged` to this group, I don't see any public API to delegate user selection of checkboxes!

Comment: the checkbox has a transparent background. Shouldn't I see the label behind it?

Comment: I'm not sure, as far as I can remember, `BEMCheckBox` has some property like `fillColor ` or something like this, try to change that too. @OlivierMATROT